# sparse or dense storage of a matrix

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with large sparse matrices that are not exactly very sparse and I'm always wondering how much sparsity is required for storage of a matrix as sparse to be beneficial? We know that sparse representation of a reasonably dense matrix could have a larger size than the original one. So is there a threshold for the density of a matrix so that it would be better to store it as sparse? I know that the answer to this question usually depends on the structure of the sparsity, etc but I was wondering if there is just some guidelines? for example I have a very large matrix with density around 42%. should I store this matrix as dense or sparse?

Comment: Presumably, it also depends on what you want to do with the matrix and whether you're interested in saving memory or computation time. Could you clarify this in your question?

Comment: @David Thanks for your involvement. I'm thinking it would be better that this question would be discussed here in general but as for my case, my concern is more towards memory and not computation time and supposing that sparsity in the matrix is not structured. But I mean I even have doubts that the sparse storage of a 42% dense matrix would be smaller in size compared to its dense storage?

Comment: Well, it certainly depends on what format your choose for storing your matrix. If you want to be sure, the best thing is certainly to just measure it in your specific use case!

Comment: Is the matrix of a specific format? Say upper triangular.

Answer (score 2):

`scipy.coo_matrix` format stores the matrix as 3 `np.arrays`.  `row` and `col` are integer indices, `data` has the same data type as the equivalent dense matrix.  So it should be straight forward to calculate the memory it will take as a function of overall shape and sparsity (as well as the data type).

`csr_matrix` may be more compact.  `data` and `indices` are the same as with `coo`, but `indptr` has a value for each row plus 1.  I was thinking that `indptr` would be shorter than the others, but I just constructed a small matrix where it was longer.  An empty row, for example, requires a value in `indptr`, but none in `data` or `indices`.  The emphasis with this format is computational efficiency.

`csc` is similar, but working with columns.  Again you should be able to the math to calculate this size.

Brief discussion of memory advantages from MATLAB (using similar storage options)
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/computational-advantages.html#brbrfxy

background paper from MATLAB designers
http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/simax.pdf
SPARSE MATRICES IN MATLAB: DESIGN AND IMPLEMENTATION